# Foreach invalid argument in images

Tags: php

My foreach loop only returns 1 image

This is my select query

> 'SELECT * FROM `members` LEFT JOIN `tattoos` ON tattoos.uid = members.uid GROUP BY members.uid'

everything displays perfect just not the tattoo_items in my for each.

If there is 25 items I want it to list 25 items if there is only 3 I want it to only list 3.

```
 while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

            $uid = $row['uid'];     
            $name = $row['name'];
            $members_pic = $row['members_pic']        
            $tattoo_items = $row['tattoo_items'];        

         echo "<div class='container'>
               <div class='row'>
                 <div class='col-lg-6'>
                    <img src='$members_pic'>
                    <p>name</p>
                   </div>                
                 </div>           
            </div>";

            echo "<div class='container'>
               <div class='row'>";          

                 foreach ((array) $tattoo_items as $value) {
                         echo "<img src='$value'>";
                     }
            echo"</div> 
            </div>";          

          }
```

Comment: you should var_dump $tattoo_items to see what is inside

Comment: I have 1 image shows in the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Change your while statement to this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

The comparison not equal to false is not required, if there is no more data the while loop stops

Comment: same result only 1 image

Comment: and it added a warning assignment in condition in zend

Comment: whats the relationship in your tables? one-one, one-many, many-one? from the sql statement it seems to be one-one

Comment: I showed you my query, I joined the 2 table tattoos.uid = members.uid

Comment: tattoos.uid = members.uid  equal the same value

Comment: I see that, but your not clear what your after. for example are there many tattos to each user?

Comment: do you see where the foreach is ok if there is a 5 6 7 or even 9 images in the database for that members.uid it will list all not just 1, I need it to echo every image in tattoos that has the same uid as that member

Comment: it only echos 1 image for that user in the foreach

Comment: that showed all the images but it also created 4 different profiles of the user for each image :-(